# Shift-Reduce and Reduce-Reduce examples and one solved examples?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, programming-languages, grammar, compiler-optimization

in simple precedence parsing (Decomposition) for following grammar we have `shift-reduce` and `reduce-reduce` conflicts. `X` is start symbol and `X'-->$X$` is Added rule. in addition `+` and `lower symbol` is terminals.

```
X'-->$X$
X-->Y | X + a
Y-->b | b + Y
```

Question: How my TA solved this question and reach to `shift-reduce` and `reduce-reduce` conflicts? any steps for this problem? it's so ambiguous for me ! maybe there are wrong answer.

Comment: Have you considered asking your TA?

Comment: No because this is for two years ago @MadPhysicist

Answer (score 1):

I tried to create the automaton using the SLR algorithm. As you can see below, there is a shift-reduce conflict for the state 1 and the look-ahead symbol `+`. You can see the item sets for the states 1 and 4.

In state 1, there is the item `r3: Y -> b .`, thus the correct action would be to reduce using the third rule.

However, state 1 also contains the item

- `r4: Y -> b . + Y`, while state 4 contains the item
- `r4: Y -> b + . Y`, thus another correct action would be to shift to state 4.

This results in one correct shift and one correct reduce action for the same cell in the automaton, which produces a shift-reduce conflict.

I cannot see a reduce-reduce conflict.

#### All items per Rule

```
r0: root -> . X EOF
r0: root -> X . EOF
r0: root -> X EOF .

r1: X -> . Y
r1: X -> Y .

r2: X -> . X + a
r2: X -> X . + a
r2: X -> X + . a
r2: X -> X + a .

r3: Y -> . b
r3: Y -> b .

r4: Y -> . b + Y
r4: Y -> b . + Y
r4: Y -> b + . Y
r4: Y -> b + Y .
```

#### Automaton

```
    +   a   b   EOF X   Y
0:          s1      2   3
1:  inv         r3      
2:  s5          acc     
3:  r1          r1      
4:          s1          6
5:      s7              
6:  r4          r4      
7:  r2          r2
```

#### Conflict

```
shift/reduce conflict for state 1 and symbol +: s4 r3
s1
r4: Y -> b . + Y
r3: Y -> b .

s4
r4: Y -> b + . Y
r3: Y -> . b
r4: Y -> . b + Y
```

Comment: I see this question and your answer, one thing is strange for me, " create the automaton " no other method is found for solving this example without automaton? It surprised me

Comment: @DaviedZuhraph A conflict is found if there is more than one valid action for a cell in the automaton. Thus, if it is possible to construct the automaton without any conflicts, then there are no conflicts. Please note, that this also depends on the algorithm, e.g. SLR, LALR, ... However, there might be other methods to check for conflicts, that I am currently unaware of.

Comment: +1. 1) I think there is a typo in your  Automaton, please check it 2) what is the meaning of "acc" and "inv"

Comment: 1) Can you give me a hint? Where is the type? 2) `acc` means the provided input is accepted. It is a valid program. `inv` means invalid. There is a conflict for that cell.

Comment: I'm not so professional, I check it and I thinks it has a  typo,  maybe I'm wrong. thanks I get it.